# Syntax Error: Comma in Query Expression of access SQL Statement

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access

Please I badly needed your help. I have the following code that returns a table from ms access displayed in a data grid view based on the user's input. But when I tried to run it, I have encountered the error "Syntax error (comma) in query expression 'lastname = '' , firstname = '' , midname = '''." Please someone help me

here is my code.

```
  Dim sql As String = "SELECT `lastname` as 'FAMILY NAME',`firstname` as 'NAME', `midname` AS 'MIDDLE NAME', `sex` as 'SEX', `birthdate` as 'BIRTHDAY', `Address` as 'ADDRESS', `barangay` AS 'BARANGAY', `patientID` AS 'PID' FROM `tblinformation_offline` WHERE lastname = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' , firstname = '" & TextBox3.Text & "' , midname = '" & TextBox4.Text & "' "
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(constring)
        cn.Open()
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds, "AccessData")
        cn.Close()
        With Me.DataGridView1
            .DataSource = ds
            .DataMember = "AccessData"
        End With
        ds = Nothing
        da.Dispose()
        cn = Nothing
```

Comment: Lot of problems here. But I would start reviewing how you write a WHERE clause. Check you database manuals (or any on-line tutorial on SQL)

Comment: What is the DB, Access or MySQL - they are 2 very different things.  You should use SQL parameters instead of concatenating strings for the query.  Hopefully no one is named `D'Artagnan` or `O'Brien`

Comment: @Steve how is the WHERE clause wrong?

Comment: @Plutonix The DB I am using is Access.. can you show me, how this done properly please?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/  There are [Thousands of Q and A here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+vb.net+sql+parameters) showing how to use Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem, a WHERE clause is a one or more conditions linked together by a logical operator like AND or OR. Your WHERE list a series of values and this is not a valid syntax

```
.... FROM `tblinformation_offline` 
     WHERE lastname =  'xxxxx' 
     AND firstname = 'yyyyyy' 
     AND midname = 'zzzzz"
```

This will fix your immediate error.
As you can see I have removed the string concatenation to let you see more clearly your errors, but now there is the problem of your use of string concatenation to build sql queries. Don't do it but use a parameterized query

In a parameterized query you use the Parameters collection of the MySqlCommand to pass your values, while the string that contains the text is filled with parameter's placeholders

```
 Dim sql As String = "SELECT ...... FROM `tblinformation_offline` " & _
      "WHERE lastname = @lname AND firstname = @fname AND midname = @mname" 
 Using cn As New OleDbConnection(constring)
 Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cn)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@lname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@fname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@mname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "AccessData")
    cn.Close()
    With Me.DataGridView1
        .DataSource = ds
        .DataMember = "AccessData"
    End With
    ds = Nothing
End Using
End Using
```

Finally in the query text used there are errors. When you write

```
"SELECT `lastname` as 'FAMILY NAME' ....
```

You are creating records where the value of the column lastname is filled with the string "FAMILY NAME" because you use the single quote character instead of the backticks as you do around the columns (the same applies to the other columns as well)

Comment: Why are the fields in the Select have `

Comment: @codeMonger123 the backticks character is used by MySql as delimiter around the column and table name. (Like the square brackets in Sql Server) They are not really required here because the columns have a standard and not confusing name, but the aliases contain spaces. Here the backticks are required